# Should I use encodeURI or encodeURIComponent for encoding URLs?

Tags: javascript

Which of these two methods should be used for encoding URLs?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3608791/632951

Comment: One major difference is that `encodeURI` won't encode `/` so: `encodeURIComponent("ac/dc")` => `ac%2Fdc` and `encodeURI("ac/dc")` => `ac/dc`

Comment: This might be helpful:  `"encodeURIComponent() and encodeURI() encode a URI by replacing URL reserved characters with their UTF-8 encoding....They differ because encodeURI does not encode queryString or hash values...URLs do not allow many special characters, like spaces or slashes. However these special characters are part of life, so URL encoding was invented."` [Source](https://love2dev.com/blog/whats-the-difference-between-encodeuri-and-encodeuricomponent)

Comment: Also see specific section titled `encodeURIComponent differs from encodeURI as follows` at:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent#Description

Answer (score 482, accepted):

It depends on what you are actually wanting to do.

`encodeURI` assumes that the input is a complete URI that might have some characters which need encoding in it.

`encodeURIComponent` will encode everything with special meaning, so you use it for components of URIs such as:

```js
const world = 'A string with symbols & characters that have special meaning?'
const uri = 'http://example.com/foo?hello=' + encodeURIComponent(world)
```

Answer (score 184):

If you're encoding a string to put in a URL component (a querystring parameter), you should call `encodeURIComponent`.

If you're encoding an existing URL, call `encodeURI`.

Comment: If i am using ajax how do i decode the url which is passed to php?

Comment: You don't. The webserver does that automatically.

Comment: @Aditya: It depends what you're doing.

Comment: @slaks .I am passing parameters via get so I want to retrieve them in php.

Comment: @david So if let's say i use encodeURICompenent to encode the parameters passed via  get then apache would give me a decoded url from which i could access the parameters?

Comment: Well. I might have spoken a bit hastily when I said the *webserver* would do it, but whatever library you use to read your form data will take care of it for you.

Comment: You need to call `encodeURIComponent` on each parameter.  (Note that your AJAX library might do that for you).  Most server-side frameworks will decode the parameters for you.

Comment: @slaks Well I am not using any ajax library , just using simple javascript.

Comment: @SLaks You're right about %20 being correct for spaces. That comment was supposed to be deleted. I poorly misdiagnosed an issue that caused my head to spin and make that comment. It's deleted now (I hope).

Answer (score 66):

Here is a summary.

1. `escape()` will not encode @ * _ + - . /

   Do not use it.
2. `encodeURI()` will not encode A-Z a-z 0-9 ; , / ? : @ & = + $ - _ . ! ~ * ' ( ) #

   Use it when your input is a complete URL like 'https://searchexample.com/search?q=wiki'
3. `encodeURIComponent()` will not encode A-Z a-z 0-9 - _ . ! ~ * ' ( )

   Use it when your input is part of a complete URL
   e.g
   `const queryStr = encodeURIComponent(someString)`

Comment: This is an excellent answer because it tells exactly what they do. However I still have a question about which should I use and when.   What if my URI -component is a complete URL? Should I then use Rule 2 or Rule 3 from above OR perhaps BOTH like encodeURIComponent ( encodeURI (theCompleteURI ))

Comment: if you want to put a complete URL into a query parameter then use encodeURIComponent e.g.
`https://example.test/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.test%2fhome`

Comment: What happens if I use encodeURIComponent to encode complete url ?   Will that break something ?

When is it necessary to use encodeURI()  and  MUST not use encodeURIComponent()

Comment: @marcg yes it will break your link. This is how a link will look like after encoded by encodeURIComponent. Now try to paste it to your URL bar, then you'll understand ;) 
'https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F4540753%2Fshould-i-use-encodeuri-or-encodeuricomponent-for-encoding-urls'

Answer (score 61):

[xkr.us](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/) has a great discussion, with examples.  To quote their summary:

> The escape() method does not encode the + character which is
>   interpreted as a space on the server side as well as generated by
>   forms with spaces in their fields. Due to this shortcoming and the
>   fact that this function fails to handle non-ASCII characters
>   correctly, you should avoid use of escape() whenever possible. The
>   best alternative is usually encodeURIComponent().
>
> escape() will not encode: @*/+
>
> Use of the encodeURI() method is a bit more specialized than escape()
>   in that it encodes for URIs as opposed to the querystring, which is
>   part of a URL. Use this method when you need to encode a string to be
>   used for any resource that uses URIs and needs certain characters to
>   remain un-encoded. Note that this method does not encode the '
>   character, as it is a valid character within URIs.
>
> encodeURI() will not encode: ~!@#$&*()=:/,;?+'
>
> Lastly, the encodeURIComponent() method should be used in most cases
>   when encoding a single component of a URI. This method will encode
>   certain chars that would normally be recognized as special chars for
>   URIs so that many components may be included. Note that this method
>   does not encode the ' character, as it is a valid character within
>   URIs.
>
> encodeURIComponent() will not encode: ~!*()'

Comment: Recently learned.  TOMCAT 9 servers are more particular about what you can send to the URL.  encodeURIComponent() appears to work better in cases where you have "spaces" in what you need to encode.  Tomcat 8 did not care but 9 is way more particular.

Comment: So in other words `encodeURI` fails if you're trying to convert a filename to a URL and the filename has `#` in it

Answer (score 46):

**encodeURI** and **encodeURIComponent** are used for different purposes.
Some of the difference are

1. **encodeURI** is used to **encode a full URL** whereas **encodeURIComponent** is used for **encoding a URI component** such as a query string.
2. There are **11 characters** which are not encoded by encodeURI, but encoded by encodeURIComponent.
   List:

| Character | encodeURI | encodeURIComponent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| # | # | %23 |
| $ | $ | %24 |
| & | & | %26 |
| + | + | %2B |
| , | , | %2C |
| / | / | %2F |
| : | : | %3A |
| ; | ; | %3B |
| = | = | %3D |
| ? | ? | %3F |
| @ | @ | %40 |

**Notes:**
**encodeURIComponent**  does not encode -_.!~*'(). If you want to these characters are encoded, you have to replace them with a corresponding UTF-8 sequence of characters

If you want to learn more about encodeURI and encodeURIComponent, please check the reference link.
[Reference Link](https://thisthat.dev/encode-uri-vs-encode-uri-component/)

Answer (score 12):

encodeURIComponent() : assumes that its argument is a portion (such as the protocol, hostname, path, or query string)
of a URI. Therefore it escapes the punctuation characters that are used to separate the portionsof a URI.

encodeURI(): is used for encoding existing url

Answer (score 12):

## Difference between `encodeURI` and `encodeURIComponent`:

`encodeURIComponent(value)` is mainly used to encode queryString parameter values, and it encodes every applicable character in `value`.  `encodeURI` ignores protocol prefix (`http://`) and domain name.

---

In very, very rare cases, when you want to implement manual encoding to encode additional characters (though they don't need to be encoded in typical cases) like: `! *` , then
you might use:

```
function fixedEncodeURIComponent(str) {
  return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!*]/g, function(c) {
    return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
  });
}
```

([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent))

Comment: You should not escape those charachters in url.

Comment: As the cited documentation says: "these characters have no formalized URI delimiting uses"

Comment: @caesarsol so, should I edit my answer. let me know your thoughts because I cant understand what that cited documentation means..

Comment: its just useless to encode these chars, unless you are doing something out of the normal URL-encoding use cases :)

Comment: `if anyone thinks it's useless to encode *, feel free to run rm * on your home directory.` @HoldOffHunger If you are taking user provided inputs and using them to run commands on your machine you have bigger issues than whether url encoding is used or not. Your comment is utterly irrelevant to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 5):

Other answers describe the purposes. Here are the characters each function **will actually convert**:

```
control = '\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0A\x0B\x0C\x0D\x0E\x0F'
        + '\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\X15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1A\x1B\x1C\x1D\x1E\x1F'
                                                                    + '\x7F'
encodeURI         (control + ' "%<>[\\]^`{|}'                             )
encodeURIComponent(control + ' "%<>[\\]^`{|}' + '#$&,:;=?' + '+/@'        )
escape            (control + ' "%<>[\\]^`{|}' + '#$&,:;=?' +       "!'()~")
```

All characters above are converted to percent-hexadecimal codes. Space to `%20`, percent to `%25`, etc. The characters below pass through unchanged.

Here are the characters the functions **will NOT convert**:

```
pass_thru = '*-._0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

encodeURI         (pass_thru + '#$&,:;=?' + '+/@' + "!'()~")
encodeURIComponent(pass_thru +                      "!'()~")
escape            (pass_thru +              '+/@'          )
```

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking to understand why encoding is necessary in the first place so I thought this would be useful to add here:

What is the purpose of encoding?
This is because only characters from the standard 128-character ASCII set are allowed in URLs. Many special characters, such as spaces and slashes, are not permitted.

For example, characters such as ~!@#$&*()=:/,;?+’ are special characters need to be encoded in URL.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35772497)