# If I am encoding a URI which will be used as a query string parameter: encodeURI or encodeURIComponent

Tags: javascript

From old post: [Should I use encodeURI or encodeURIComponent for encoding URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540753/encodeuri-or-encodeuricomponent), it said:

```
encodeURI assumes that the input is a complete URI that might have some 
characters which need encoding in it.

encodeURIComponent will encode everything with special meaning, so 
you use it for components of URIs such as
```

What if I need to encode the `URI` as query string parameter?

e.g.

```
var url = "http://example.com/?next=" + encodeURI(url) 

or


var url = "http://example.com/?next=" + encodeURIComponent(url)
```

Comment: You can check this link if you want to know differnces in encoding characters [http://www.javascripter.net/faq/escape-encodeuri-lower-ascii.htm](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/escape-encodeuri-lower-ascii.htm)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you want to encode a query string, use `encodeURIComponent`. The reason is simple: among a few other chars, it'll encode the forward slash and amersand that `encodeURI` will not.

**encodeURIComponent**

What's the use? Say you want to encode a URL and pass it in the query string, this will let you encode all the characters so you get something like this:

```
encodeURIComponent('http://abc.com/my page.html?name=bob&foo=bar')
```

to get the result

```
"http%3A%2F%2Fabc.com%2Fmy%20page.html%3Fname%3Dbob%26foo%3Dbar"
```

You can now safely pass that as a query string like so:

```
http://mysite.com/foo=http%3A%2F%2Fabc.com%2Fmy%20page.html%3Fname%3Dbob%26foo%3Dbar
```

Notice how both URLs have a query string parameter `foo` but that's OK because the encoded URL has that encoded. The entire `foo` parameter is

```
http%3A%2F%2Fabc.com%2Fmy%20page.html%3Fname%3Dbob%26foo%3Dbar
```

There is no conflict with the `foo=bar` in the second, encoded, URL.

**encodeURI**

Now, if you want to encode a complete URL that you have already, use `encodeURI`.

```
encodeURI('http://abc.com/my page.html?name=bob&foo=bar')
```

Will give you

```
"http://abc.com/my%20page.html?name=bob&foo=bar"
```

Notice how that keeps the URL valid and, in this instance, only encodes the space. If you were to run `encodeURIComponent` on that, you'd get the mess you see in my first example.

**What characters are encoded?**

As yabol commented in your first post, this page shows you the [Differences between encodeURI, encodeURIComponent, and escape: lower ASCII characters](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/escape-encodeuri-lower-ascii.htm). You notice specifically that `encodeURIComponent` encodes the following chars that `encodeURI` does not:

```
chr     encodeURI(chr)  encodeURIComponent(chr)
 +           +               %2B
 /           /               %2F
 @           @               %40
 #           #               %23
 $           $               %24
 &           &               %26
 ,           ,               %2C
 :           :               %3A
 ;           ;               %3B
 =           =               %3D
 ?           ?               %3F
```

**Your question**

You are correct in using `encodeURIComponent` because you're encoding a URL for a query string. This goes back to my first example. If your query-string URL (the one you're encoding) has a query string, you want that to be part of `next`, not part of your main URL.

**Wrong**

```
"http://example.com/?next=" + encodeURI('http://abc.com/my page.html?name=bob&foo=bar')
"http://example.com/?next=http://abc.com/my%20page.html?name=bob&foo=bar"
```

Your example.com url has two query string parameters: `next` and `foo`

**Right**

```
"http://example.com/?next=" + encodeURIComponent('http://abc.com/my page.html?foo=bar')
"http://example.com/?next=http%3A%2F%2Fabc.com%2Fmy%20page.html%3Fname%3Dbob%26foo%3Dbar"
```

Your example.com url contains only one query string parameter: `next`

Comment: Spot on. But with 10 seconds of googling, OP would have found this out himself. When it comes to JavaScript, there is documentation all over the place. In my opinion this question doesn't belong on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

If U need to encode the `URI` as a query string parameter, then you should definitely go with (2)

```
var url = "http://example.com/?next=" + encodeURIComponent(query_url);
```

take for example google translator, whenever you type the address in the Translate Section, The address is converted to a URI Component and then passed on to the google servers

If any URL need to be used as a component, then `encodeURIComponent(String);` is your best bet

Answer (score 1):

The second answer in the question you linked already says it pretty clearly:
"If you're encoding a string to put in a URL component (a querystring parameter), you should call encodeURIComponent.

If you're encoding an existing URL, call encodeURI."

So in your example encodeURIComponent is the right one.

Comment: Thanks! What is the point of `encodeURI` then? If i am not going to put them as part of the URL? Any use case?

Comment: This is more like a comment than an answer.