# Angular encoding accepting backslash

Tags: java, angular, rest

I am having an application using Angular, which communicates with backend via rests. I am facing a problem with encoding of my questionares.

Angular part:

```
  searchCase(searchText: string): Observable<Case[]> {
    const encodedText = encodeURIComponent(searchText);
    return this.http.get<Case[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/case/search/${encodedText}`);
  }
```

Rest:

```
public List<Case> searchCase(
        @PathParam("searchedText") String searchedText) {
    return caseManagement.searchCase(searchedText);
}
```

For any input, this works totally fine, except for backslash. Then, it does not even reach my backend rest part. How can I go over it?

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555230/if-i-am-encoding-a-uri-which-will-be-used-as-a-query-string-parameter-encodeuri . Actually it is considered as a part of your URL, so follow the steps of @sachleen and it will work fine!

Comment: Can you give us any string examples?

Comment: @AndrejBuday an example would be "12\65" - just a random string including backslash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that it was enough to use btoa instead:

```
searchCase(searchText: string): Observable<Case[]> {
    const encodedText = btoa(searchText);
    return this.http.get<Case[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/case/search/${encodedText}`);
  }
```

And then decode it on backend side and seems to work totally fine.