# JQuery - Ajax: encodeUriComponent not working (EncodeUri does)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, urlencode

In a small asp.net webclient I have the following Ajax-call.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Search.aspx?action=GetDocumentInfoByChronicleId&" + querystring
})
.success(function (msg) {
    $("#documentcontent").html(msg);
})
```

The `querystring` works for default characters but appears to be non-working when using special characters (see example below)

```
objectId=09028139800c59e3&Db=DIV_Firm <== Works
objectId=090281>>773c5983&Db=DIV_Firm <== Non Working
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540753/encodeuri-or-encodeuricomponent?lq=1) (and many more posts on SO i opted to change my ajax-calls as follows (`EncodeUriComponent`). But none appear to be working (**even with the original querystring**).

Could someone point out to me what i'm exactly doing wrong?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Search.aspx?action=GetDocumentInfoByChronicleId&" + encodeURIComponent(querystring)
})
.success(function (msg) {
    $("#documentcontent").html(msg);
})
```

**Note:** `EncodeUri` appears to be working though. But i'd prefer to use `EncodeUriComponent`

Comment: Where are you getting the querystrings from? There's a built in way to pass data in $.ajax, no need for querystrings.

Comment: Querystring are being built by myself. I need to send data to server based on the userinput. What do you mean with "There's a built in way to pass data in $.ajax?" Do you mean using ´{data: ... }?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wouldn't it be a lot easier if there was some way to pass data when doing ajax calls, oh wait, there is, using the `data` option

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url  : "Search.aspx",
    data : {
        action   : 'GetDocumentInfoByChronicleId',
        objectId : '09028139800c59e3',
        Db       : 'DIV_Firm'
    }
});
```

jQuery will create the querystring for you and escape it appropriately

As a sidenote, `encodeURI` is exactly what you should be using to encode a querystring containing `?`, `&` etc. as `encodeUriComponent` will escape those characters as well, making the querystring invalid, but the method posted above is much simpler as you don't have to worry about encoding at all.

Comment: Will try so directly! I'll get back to you soon.

Comment: Sweet! it works! Thanks Man! I didn't know ´$.ajax - data escapes´ it automatically :) i'll approve the answer as soon as SO allows me too

Comment: It does, arrays, objects, strings and whatever can be passed directly to $.ajax, and jQuery will try to make sense of it and create a valid querystring.

Comment: I don't know if at one point jQuery didn't automatically do this, but there are many S/O questions about this with answers directing users TO encode values AND pass them via `data: { .. }`

Comment: @JoeBrockhaus - jQuery has done this for many years, if you pass it a value it will convert it into `form/www-endoded` data, but some people have controllers that expect JSON on the backend, and then you'd have to set a content header and stringify the object before sending it. As long as the server expects a form, this is the way to go.