# Ember QueryParams with "=" character

Tags: ember.js

I have a relatively simple problem here but cant find a solution to it yet. Am using Ember and calling a route with query params. The code is below.

import Ember from "ember";

```
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    queryParams : ['user_id','custom_lis_person_name_given']
    user_id : null,
    custom_lis_person_name_given : null
});
```

So now lets say i am calling my Route with the following url,

```
localhost:4200/index.html#/route1?user_id=123456&custom_lis_person_name_given=hello
```

Now the values of the query params are

```
user_id = 123456
custom_lis_person_name_given = hello
```

Now if i change my url to look like

```
localhost:4200/index.html#/route1?user_id=12345=6&custom_lis_person_name_given=hello
localhost:4200/index.html#/route1?user_id=123456=&custom_lis_person_name_given=hello
```

Now the value are calculated as

```
user_id = 12345 or user_id=123456
custom_lis_person_name_given = hello
```

So basically the value ends where it sees a = sign in the query parameter value. Is there a workaround for this? i need the user_id=**"12345=6"** or **"123456="**

Maybe there are some hooks in controller or route which can do this. I tried **serializeQueryParam** and **deserializeQueryParam** but it did not help.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I have one workaround by escaping the queryParamter before craeting the URL. i just did **escape('123456=')** and it worked. But in the App the url gets created in the backend. It would be better if i could fix it completely at UI side

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

```
encodeURIComponent(url)
```

?

That one should do the work. Note that you still have to encode the `=` sign, so that should be the correct one.

The difference between `encdeURI` and `encodeURIComponent` is well described here:
[Should I use encodeURI or encodeURIComponent for encoding URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540753/encodeuri-or-encodeuricomponent) in the accepted answer.

EDIT:

If you want to manually edit the link and check if it works, just replace `=` with `%3D`, the result of `encodeURIComponent("=")`.

Comment: The situation is like the whole URL(ember route + query params) is generated in java file and is called in the browser. Yea so one solution is to do escape(url) from java side. But i wanted to know if there is something i could do from UI side itself.