# Javascript HTML forms : unicode user input to unicode output

Tags: javascript, unicode, forms

I'm trying to make a simple multi-search tool for learning German.  When I put in certain characters, they change.  For example, ü is %FC, ä is %E4, ö is $F6, ß is %DF.  I assume somewhere the characters are being converted to some other character set other than Unicode

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <script language="javascript" charset="UTF-8">
        function basicSearch()
        {
            //document.basicForm.basicWord.value = '\u1495';
            var basicSubmit=document.basicForm;
            var basicWord = escape(basicSubmit.basicWord.value);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = basicWord;
            window.open("https://translate.google.com/#de/en/" + basicWord);
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="basicForm" onSubmit="return basicSearch();" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input type="text" name="basicWord">
    <input type="submit" name="SearchSubmit" value="Search">
  </form><br>

 <p id="demo"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var basicWord = escape(basicSubmit.basicWord.value);
```

JavaScript's `escape()`/`unescape()` encoding is a bizarre custom format you almost never want to use. For encoding URL parameters using the actual real URL rules, the function you want instead is `encodeURIComponent()`.

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = basicWord;
```

Avoid writing HTML markup to the document, you get HTML-injection problems which can lead to cross-site scripting security holes. Write to `textContent` instead to write normal text.

```
window.open("https://translate.google.com/#de/en/" + basicWord);
```

(Incidentally Google Translate also accepts form parameters: `q` for text to translate, `sl` for source and `tl` for target language. So FWIW you could do this with a simple form without JS.)

Comment: Thank you bobince!

Answer (score 1):

Its a good idea to consider http encoding any URIs you are manually constructing.  In this case we can use `encodeURIComponent` on the text of the input to properly http encode data passed in the URI.

```
// früh -> early
var basicWord = encodeURIComponent(basicSubmit.basicWord.value);
// basicWord = 'fr%C3%BCh';
```

Other cases might warrant using `encodeURI`.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540753/should-i-use-encodeuri-or-encodeuricomponent-for-encoding-urls) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both.  If anyone is interested, below is the final coding.  I made it to help create flash cards for ANKI using Gabriel Wyner's youtube vids and his multi-tool.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>


function basicSearch() {
  var basicSubmit=document.basicForm;
  var basicWord = encodeURIComponent(basicSubmit.searchterms.value);
  window.open("https://de.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?search=" + basicWord + "&title=Spezial:Suche&go=Seite&searchToken=480i5tddc2tqpr6njyi8gx2oa");
  window.open("http://forvo.com/search/" + basicWord + "/");
  window.open("https://www.google.de/search?q=" + basicWord + "&biw=1280&bih=611&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOydnfssfRAhVCqlQKHaPSDvoQ_AUIBigB#q=" + basicWord + "&tbm=isch&tbs=isz:m");
  window.open("https://translate.google.com/#de/en/" + basicWord);
  return false;

}

function actionSearch() {
  var actionSubmit=document.actionForm;
  var actionWord = encodeURIComponent(actionSubmit.searchterms.value);
  window.open("https://www.google.de/search?q=" + actionWord + "&biw=1280&bih=611&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiiwtDttMfRAhVkx1QKHc6PCgMQ_AUIBigB#tbs=isz:m%2Citp:animated&tbm=isch&q=" + actionWord);
  return false;
}


</script>

<form name="basicForm" onSubmit="return basicSearch();">
 Search for a basic word: 
 <input type="text" name="searchterms">
 <input type="submit" name="SearchSubmit" value="Search">
</form><br>
<form name="actionForm" onSubmit="return actionSearch();">
 Search google for animation: 
 <input type="text" name="searchterms">
 <input type="submit" name="SearchSubmit" value="Search">
</form><br>

<a href="https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Verzeichnis:Deutsch/Redewendungen">German quotes/sayings</a>

<h2>English links for gifs: (for verbs or other)</h2>
<a href="http://giphy.com/">http://giphy.com/</a><br>
<a href="http://www.reactiongifs.com/">http://www.reactiongifs.com/</a><br>
<a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/">https://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/</a><br>
<a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/reactiongifs/">https://www.reddit.com/r/reactiongifs/</a><br>
<a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/analogygifs">https://www.reddit.com/r/analogygifs</a><br>
<a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/HighQualityGifs/">https://www.reddit.com/r/HighQualityGifs/</a><br>
<a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/DANCEGIFS/">https://www.reddit.com/r/DANCEGIFS/</a><br>
<a href="http://www.gifbin.com/">http://www.gifbin.com/</a><br>


</body>
</html>
```