# Redirect User to encoded URL-Variable

Tags: javascript, html, url

I am currently working on a URL, which encodes the URL entered by URL variable. The user is then redirected to `http://example.net/?enc_url=THE ENCODED LINK`.

This is my previous code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        setTimeout(function() {
            var uri = <?php echo $_GET["url"]; ?>
            var res = encodeURI(uri)
            location.href = 'http://example.com"/?enc_url={$res}'
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Please help me, but remember that I do not have much experience with PHP yet. Thanks for any help!

Greetings!

Comment: question is unclear. what you want exactly and where you are facing problem?

Comment: Use browser debug console to debug your javascript code. There is a closing `)` missing of `setTimeout`. furthermore: js template strings (`{$res}`) can be used within `\`` quotes only not within `'` quotes.

Comment: Also, it has nothing to do with PHP, has it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only PHP:

```
<?php
$enc_url = urlencode($_GET['url']);
header("Location: http://example.com/?enc_url=$enc_url");
?>
```

JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function() {
    var uri = "<?php echo urlencode($_GET["url"]); ?>";
    location.href = `http://example.com/?enc_url=${uri}`;
}, 3000);
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use PHP syntax in Javascript. In Javascript use concatenation.

```
var res = encodeURIComponent(uri);
location.href = 'http://example.com/?enc_url=' + res;
```

You're also missing the closing `)` for the `setTimeout()` call. And you should be using `encodeURIComponent`, not `encodeURI`; see [Should I use encodeURI or encodeURIComponent for encoding URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540753/should-i-use-encodeuri-or-encodeuricomponent-for-encoding-urls)