# AJAX api request missing some data at controller $_GET

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter-3

When i'm trying to send data(url) to API with ajax request, PHP CI controller not considering all parameters in $_GET. it just accepting up to &.

Is there any error in passing parameters? Please help. I tried passing direct url and encodeURI.

JQuery code

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "<?= ROOT?>welcome/ajaxapiget",
        data: encodeURI(http://localhost/webapi/list?categories[]=3&categories[]=12),
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

PHP

```
function ajaxapiget() {
    $url = $_GET;`//its getting url as http://localhost/webapi/list?categories[]=3`
    $curl = curl_init();
    ........
    ........
    response $response;
}
```

also tried like this

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "<?= ROOT?>welcome/ajaxapiget",
        data: 'url=http://localhost/webapi/list?categories[]=3&categories[]=12)',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

PHP

```
function ajaxapiget() {
    $url = $_GET(url);`//its getting url as http://localhost/webapi/list?categories[]=3`
    $curl = curl_init();
    ........
    ........
    response $response;
}
```

When i alert

before sending request

```
url=http://localhost/webapi/courselist?categories[]=15&categories[]=17
```

response from controller (alert at ajax success)

```
$url = $_GET('url');
echo $url
```

alert response

```
http://localhost/webapi/courselist?categories[]=15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved this with `encodeURIComponent`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "<?= ROOT?>welcome/ajaxapiget",
    data: 'url=http://localhost/webapi/list?' + encodeURIComponent('categories[]=15&categories[]=17'),
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

now the result is

```
http://localhost/webapi/courselist?categories[]=15&categories[]=17
```

> encodeURIComponent will encode everything with special meaning, so you
>   use it for components of URIs

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4540785

Answer (score 0):

Try this

JQuery code

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "<?= ROOT?>welcome/ajaxapiget",
        data: {url:'http://localhost/webapi/list?categories[]=3&categories[]=12'},
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

PHP code

```
function ajaxapiget() {
    $url = $this->input->get('url');//Getting $url as http://localhost/webapi/list?categories[]=3&categories[]=12
    $curl = curl_init();
    ........
    ........
    response $response;
}
```

Use `$this->input->get()` instead of `$_GET[]` in Codeingiter

Comment: thanks for reply. this is not working. Getting same result(up to &) not the entire url :(

Comment: Can you show me the response in alert by printing the $_GET

do print_r($_GET); die;

Comment: before ajax request url=http://localhost/webapi/courselist?categories[]=15&categories[]=17
result from controller http://localhost/webapi/courselist?categories[]=15

Comment: Are you sure you passed data in ajax request  like {url:'http://localhost/webapi/list?categories[]=3&categories[]=12'}and used $this->input->get('url') or $_GET["url"], because there is no method like $_GET(). It should produce error.

Comment: Yes data i'm sending is same as mentioned but in the controller it not considering from & i tried with normal test string as abcd&efgh but at controller it asscepting only abcd.

Comment: Thanks for your help finally working with encodeURIComponent