# why cant i put a var in a encodeURI?

Tags: jquery, var, encodeuricomponent

why is this working?

```
var movieName = encodeURI("deadpool");
var url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=" + apiKey + "&query=" + movieName;
```

and this not?; iven put a console log to check and that works

```
var movieName = $(".shown .title").html();
console.log(movieName);

var url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=" + apiKey + "&query=" + encodeURI(movieName);
```

Comment: I suspect the HTML has some extra whitespace around the name, try `.html().trim()` to remove it.

Comment: BTW, you should use `encodeURIComponent`, not `encodeURI`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540753/should-i-use-encodeuri-or-encodeuricomponent-for-encoding-urls

Comment: In what way isn't it working? Can you show the output of `console.log(url)`?

Comment: https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=94a2f36cd4e27626b6a7a07766a76196&query=deadpool

Comment: That looks fine, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML may have whitespace around the title, which you need to remove.

```
var movieName = $(".shown .title").html().trim();
```

Also, you should probably use `.text()` rather than `.html()`, in case there are embedded HTML tags.

```js
var apiKey = "key";

var movieName = encodeURIComponent("deadpool");
var url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=" + apiKey + "&query=" + movieName;
console.log(url);

var movieName = $(".shown .title").html().trim();
console.log(movieName);

var url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=" + apiKey + "&query=" + encodeURIComponent(movieName);
console.log(url);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shown">
<div class="title">
deadpool
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work, and there are also no embedded items in the .title element.
thanks anyway

Comment: If you're using jQuery `$.get`, it's better to put the parameters in a data object rather than creating the query string by hand. It will encode everything properly.

Comment: I've added a snippet showing that both of them create the same URL.

Comment: `var movieName = $(".shown .title").text().trim();
console.log(movieName);
var url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=" + apiKey + "&query=" + encodeURI(movieName);
console.log(url);`

it is working with this code, thanks a lot