# Why Google Maps refuse to render when a hashtag sign is present in the address?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, ecmascript-6

I am attempting to render this address: `universal music 2100 Colorado Ave Suite #1` which resolves to this: https://maps.google.com/maps?q=universal%20music%202100%20Colorado%20Ave%20Suite%20#1&t=&z=9&ie=UTF8&iwloc=&output=embed

Noticed the `#1`? If I change that to `universal music 2100 Colorado Ave Suite No 1` it resolves to https://maps.google.com/maps?q=universal%20music%202100%20Colorado%20Ave%20Suite%20No%201&t=&z=9&ie=UTF8&iwloc=&output=embed and it renders perfectly.

This is what I have:

```
const txtOnMap = 'universal music 2100 Colorado Ave Suite #1';

const handleMapUrl = `https://maps.google.com/maps?q=${txtOnMap}&t=&z=9&ie=UTF8&iwloc=&output=embed`;

<iframe frameBorder="0" src={encodeURI(handleMapUrl)} />
```

I have tried some others addresses with hashtags in them and it happened the same.

Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 2):

`encodeURI` doesn't encode the `#` sign, so it remains a fragment identifier (not part of the URL sent to Google, but a local "jump to element with this ID" indicator).

You don't actually want to encode the whole URL in any event, you need to encode one *component* of it, so use `encodeURIComponent` on that component alone:

```
const txtOnMap = encodeURIComponent('universal music 2100 Colorado Ave Suite #1');
```

which produces the properly escaped:

```
"universal%20music%202100%20Colorado%20Ave%20Suite%20%231"
```

See more at [Should I use encodeURI or encodeURIComponent for encoding URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4540753/364696)

Comment: You can also refer to the URL Encoding documentation of Google Maps Platform: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/url-encoding

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the hashtag needs to be escaped in the URL as it's a special character. This is done by converting it to `%23`

Working example is:

```
const txtOnMap = 'universal music 2100 Colorado Ave Suite #1'.replace('#','%23');


const handleMapUrl = `https://maps.google.com/maps?q=${txtOnMap}&t=&z=9&ie=UTF8&iwloc=&output=embed`;

var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = encodeURI(handleMapUrl);

<iframe frameBorder="0" src={encodeURI(handleMapUrl)} />
```