# How to convert from a filename to a URL in Electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

Let's say I get a directory listing of .jpg files and then want to display them

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readDirSync(someAbsolutePathToFolder)
    .filter(f => f.endsWith('.jpg'))
    .forEach(filename => {
        const img = new Image();
        const filepath  = path.join(someAbsolutePathToFolder, filename);
        img.src = `file://${filepath.replace(/\\/g, '/')}`;
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    });
```

This will fail. As just one example, if the listing I got had names like

```
#001-image.jpg
#002-image.jpg
```

the code above results in URLs like

```
file://some/path/#001-image.jpg
```

Which you can see is a problem. The URL will be cut at the `#`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540753/should-i-use-encodeuri-or-encodeuricomponent-for-encoding-urls) claims I should be using `encodeURI` but that also fails as it leaves the `#` unescaped.

Using `encodeURIComponent` also does not work. It replaces `/` and `:` and space and Electron does not find the file, at least not on Windows.

Up until this point I had something like this

```
const filepath  = path.join(someAbsolutePathToFolder, filename).replace(/\\/g, '/');
img.src = `file://${filepath.split('/').map(encodeURIComponent).join('/')}`;
```

but that also fails on windows because drive letters get convert from `c:\dir\file` to `c%3a\dir\file` which then appears to be a relative path to electron.

So I have more special cases trying to check for `[a-z]:` at at the beginning of the path as well as `\\` for UNC paths.

Today I ran into the `#` issue mentioned above and I'm expecting more time bombs are waiting for me so I'm asking...

What is the correct way to convert a filename to a URL in a cross platform way?

Or to be more specific, how to solve the problem above. Given a directory listing of absolute paths of image files on the local platform generate URLs that will load those images if assigned to the `src` property of an image.

Comment: Try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-join

Comment: url-join completely and utterly fails to solve a single problem mentioned above.

Comment: encodeURI encodes only non-latin symbols

Answer (score 1):

You can use Node's (v10+) `pathToFileURL`:

```
import { pathToFileURL } from 'url';
const url = pathToFileURL('/some/path/#001-image.jpg');
img.src = url.href;
```

See: https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_pathtofileurl_path

Answer (score -1):

This works fine for me:

```
const open = require('open')
const path = require('path')

const FILE_NAME = 'картинка.jpg'
const filePath  = path.join(__dirname, FILE_NAME)
const fileUrl = `file:///${ filePath.split('\\').join('/') }`

console.log(fileUrl)
open(fileUrl)
```

Comment: actually you don't need to encode your URL to open it locally, i have edited my answer

Comment: Thakns but that solution doesn't work as pointed out in the question. Be in Windows. Name the file `foo#bar.jpg`. Assign it to an image as specified in the question.