# javascript : how to replace special symbols/characters that will break your query string in your URL

Tags: javascript, regex, url, replace, uri

I have this components in my URL --

```
var myType="Air B&B";
var myID="RestInPeace";
var myURL="http://myhome.com?type="+myType+"&name="+myID;
alert(myURL);  //http://myhome.com?type=Air B&B&id=RestInPeace
```

The '&' inside myType has broken your query here:

[http://myhome.com?type=Air B&B&id=RestInPeace](https://myhome.com?type=Air%20B&B&name=RestInPeace)

The page relies on the id to locate the record.  It won't get it because the '&' inside the type has broke the query!  Any uri sensitive characters inside myType needs to treated so it won't break the query.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since the second param is not the key to load the record, I will sacrifice the '&' in the type param.

**These characters will break your query in your URI : $ & : ' " < > [ ] + { }**.  See below the quick replace by escaping those symbols inside [] : meaning any ONE of those symbols inside []

```
var myType="Air B&B";
var myID="RestInPeace";
var myURL="http://myhome.com?type="+myType.replace(/[\$\&\'\"\:\<\>\[\]\{\}\+]/g, '^')+"&name="+myID;
alert(myURL);  //http://myhome.com?type=Air B^B&name=RestInPeace
```

Now the '&' inside myType is replaced. And the query is preserved.

[http://myhome.com?type=Air B^B&name=RestInPeace](https://myhome.com?type=Air%20B%5EB&name=RestInPeace)

Comment: This is no solution - it continues following the wrong road. And the space in the URL isn't properly encoded either. Good luck with even more chaos once `äß` or `ゾーン` or another question mark is used as "query".

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is using URL().
Create a new URL using

```
var myURL = new URL('http://myhome.com');
```

Then append search parameters like

```
var myType="Air B&B";
var myID="RestInPeace";
myURL.searchParams.set('type',myType);
myURL.searchParams.set('name',myID);
```

This will return an object like

```
hash: ""
host: "myhome.com"
hostname: "myhome.com"
href: "http://myhome.com/?type=Air+B%26B&name=RestInPeace"
origin: "http://myhome.com"
password: ""
pathname: "/"
port: ""
protocol: "http:"
search: "?type=Air+B%26B&name=RestInPeace"
searchParams: URLSearchParams {}
username: ""
```

So basically it will preserve your query automatically

Answer (score 1):

Since version 1.5 ([ECMA-262 3rd edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262-arch.htm), December 1999) JavaScript supports the functions `encodeURI()` and [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) for exactly this job. I have no idea how you two guys could have overseen this.

See also the question [Should I use encodeURI or encodeURIComponent for encoding URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4540753/4299358)

Comment: It works yes and no.  It works in normal circumstances. It didn't work when I pass that url to a server page for security check such as 'http://SafeWay.aspx?' + myURL.  Probably my SafeWay app didn't decode those encode correctly. To quick fix for my production (for now), I just replaced those sensitive characters in one-line.

Comment: It works 100% once one understands how HTTP URLs must look like as per [RFC 1738](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1738) and which part is the path and where parameters start. A `?` should only occur once to separate all parameters - if parameters themself use `?` again it must be encoded. No magic here, only logic applied. Your example `'SafeWay.aspx?' + myURL` indicates you yet haven't understood what a parameter is and why they cannot use all characters.

Comment: All it is the url with encoded parameters is a parameter itself to another url which is the safeway app. Yes it needs to be processed after the app requested it.  Yes in my case encodeURIComponent works 100 % with some processing on being consumed.