# Regex to replace only some / characters inside strings

Tags: javascript, regex

How to get regex with replace method? In my case I've got string which uses char / between.

**input:**

```
var string = "cn/" + companyName + "/st/" + state + "/ic/" + incCi + "/pr/" + priority + "/es/" + emplSystem + "/mc/" + mainCategory + "/sc/" + subCategory + "/ty/" + type;
```

**output:**

```
"cn/Nemesis Group/st/2/ic/null/pr/1 - High/es/null/mc/Add/Button/sc/Core/Label/ty/str"
```

variable mainCategory and subCategory returns string 'Add/Button' and 'Core/Label'

How to replace 'Add/Button' to 'Add%2FButton' and 'Core/Label' to 'Core%2FLabel' without changing any other char?

```
string.replace("\/", "%2F")
```

will change all char / to %2F

Comment: Have you looked at how to encode an URL in JS?

Comment: You need to do the replacement on the source strings `mainCategory` and `subCategory`, not on the final string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `encodeURIComponent()` and `decodeURIComponent()` to transform this String

Example:

```js
const companyName = "Company",
  state = "State",
  incCi = "IncCi",
  priority = "Priority",
  emplSystem = "EmplSystem",
  mainCategory = 'Add/Button',
  subCategory = 'Core/Label',
  type = "Type";

var string = "cn/" + companyName + "/st/" + state + "/ic/" + incCi + "/pr/" + priority + "/es/" + emplSystem +
  "/mc/" + encodeURIComponent(mainCategory) +
  "/sc/" + encodeURIComponent(subCategory) + "/ty/" + type;

console.log(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are looking to encode the url. You can use `encodeURI` in JS to encode a url.

```
let encodedURL = encodeURI(url);
```

You can read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp).

If you want to encode the string altogether without ignoring any domain related parts, you can us `encodeURIComponent()`

```
let encodedURL = encodeURIComponent(url);
```

You can read more about their differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4540785/3126835).

EDIT:

If you are not encoding a url and you just want to repalce  `/` with `%2F` only in `mainCategory` and `subCategory` then you need to run the regex on the string itself before joining them.

```
var string = "cn/" + companyName + 
    "/st/" + state + 
    "/ic/" + incCi + 
    "/pr/" + priority + 
    "/es/" + emplSystem + 
    "/mc/" + mainCategory.replace("\/", "%2F")  +
     "/sc/" + subCategory.replace("\/", "%2F")  + 
    "/ty/" + type;
```

Comment: @mplungjan but that will encode all the characters, I thought OP only wanted to change '/'.

Comment: Sure, if there are OTHER special chars, but if not, the the encode will work too