# JavaScript preserve query format using Next.js Router

Tags: javascript, react-router, next.js, router

How to redirect while preserving the original query param format for example:

Original Query: `localhost/login?callback=/shreyas/profile?action=follow`

So if want to go register page i used the following code to preserve the callback value, but it somehow converts the `?`, `/` & `=` symbols, which i don't want to be.

example problem: `http://localhost:3000/register?callback=%2Fshreyas%2Fprofile%3Faction%3Dfollow`

needed: `http://localhost:3000/register?callback=/shreyas/profile?action=follow`

#### Code

```js
const redirectWithCallback = (location) => {
        if (router.query && router.query.callback) {

            router.push({
                pathname: location,
                query: {
                    callback: router.query.callback
                },
            }, null, { shallow: false })
        } else window.location.pathname = location

    }
```

##### Before marking duplicate, these questions didn't helped:

- [Encode URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript)
- [Should I use encodeURI or encodeURIComponent for encoding URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540753/should-i-use-encodeuri-or-encodeuricomponent-for-encoding-urls?lq=1)