# Passing json_encoded PHP array to JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, function, get

I am trying to take a PHP array and pass it into a JavaScript function, so I can send it in a GET request. I tried to use JSON encode to pass it through, but nothing seems to work. JavaScript does not accept the array.

Here is my code, in the steps I took to get to the issue.

My array looked like this:

```php
Array ([0] => this [1] => is [2] => data )
```

So I decided to use the best solution for the job, `json_encode`

Now my array looks like this in PHP:

```php
$array = ["this","is","data"]
```

I then made my javascript function with the get request

```js
function getRequestFunction(array){

$('#div').load("path/path/section="&array="+encodeURI(array));

}
```

Next I called the function and passed the function in.

```js
getRequestFunction('<?php echo $array; ?>');
```

So I have passed my array to my JavaScript function. Unfortunately, when I run this code, my console says:

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

I thought, as my array is now JSON, it should pass to the function? Can JavaScript not accept JSON as a parameter? How else can I get this array to my function, in a format to be passed as a GET request?

Comment: Well you pass your array as a string to the function, and also this : ```"path/path/section="&array="``` is invalid js

Comment: Still getting invalid token errors unfortunatly.

Comment: There isn't enough of your code here to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ise `json_encode()` to convert to a JS object literal, then `JSON.stringify()` in the argument to the function.

```
getRequestFunction(JSON.stringify(<?php echo json_encode($array); ?>));
```

You should also use `encodeURIComponent()` rather than `encodeURI()`, since you're encoding a single parameter. See [Should I use encodeURI or encodeURIComponent for encoding URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540753/should-i-use-encodeuri-or-encodeuricomponent-for-encoding-urls) for the difference.