# Does the URL.toString() Functon encode the URL

Tags: javascript, url

I have the following example code:

```
const url = new URL("http://example.com");
url.searchParams.append("name", "Mustermann");
url.searchParams.append("question", "how does the URL.toString() function work?");
window.open(url.toString(), '_self');
```

My question is does the URL encode the different searchParams?
If it encodes the URL what function does it use?
Is the encodeURI() Function or the encodeURIComponent() Function used or is it something different.

Comment: if my memory serves me right, `encodeURI()` came far before `URL` object existed. the difference between `encodeURI()` and `encodeURIComponent()` already explained in [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4540783).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the URL object automatically encodes the values of the search parameters when you use methods like `append()`.

It uses a similar encoding to `encodeURIComponent()` where it percent-encodes special characters to ensure that the URL is valid and doesn't contain characters that might be misinterpreted.

For more detail read the [documentation on the URL object](https://javascript.info/url#encoding-strings)